# MINIO S3 IAM Policy granting R/W access by Username using Active Directory Authentication

Tags: amazon-s3, active-directory, policy, minio, identity-management

I have a minio S3 instance with identity management via Active Directory. I can authenticate users and get their assigned groups. I also can map the policy (shown below) to members of certain groups.

What I want to do now is to give read/write access to any authenticated user for a bucket which is named after the username. E.g. user `test` should have r/w access to bucket `test`.

The policy below is doing exactly that in a *non-LDAP* configuration. **But when I activate the LDAP identity management it fails in the following way:**

- Users *can* see their bucket (which means, that user-group-policy mapping works)
- Users *can* list files in their bucket
- **BUT:** users **cannot** put any object into their bucket and also **cannot** read listed files (which they can in the non-LDAP setting with the very same policy!)

I really appreciate any idea or hint.

Thanks in advance,

~dymat

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::${aws:username}"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::${aws:username}/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**EDIT:** Using the mc cli client the permissions seems to work as expected. This hints to problems in the minio webfrontend. Do I need to set additional permissions for the web frontend to work?